# .swf in iFrame. Works only in Chrome

Tags: html, iframe, flash

I have a website with a .swf file in an iframe. If I open this site in Chrome, everything works fine. The iframe is showing as expected. If I open the same site in Firefox or Safari, the browser tries to download the file instead of showing it (it shows a blank space and not the .swf file).
This happens local and on a webserver.

Has anyone an idea?

I implement the file like this:

```
<iframe width="500" height="500" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="path/to/file/myFile.swf" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

thanks!

Comment: I just used your code with an SWF file I have and it worked in Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

Comment: hm that's really weired. I tried to implement other .swf files, but firefox and safari are always trying to download the file instead of showing. Is there something messed up with my browser?